# How to add a GWT click listener to an Image?

Tags: gwt

I want to click on an image and therefore want to register (e.g.) a ClickHandler. The image I get from a ClientResource. This works so far to set the image into a table cell:

```
MyResources.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected();
Image colorImage = new Image( MyResources.INSTANCE.colorImage() );
Element colorImageElement = colorImage.getElement();

colorImage.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  System.out.println( event );
 }
} );

TableElement table = Document.get().createTableElement();
TableRowElement headRow = table.insertRow(-1);
headRow.insertCell(-1).appendChild( colorImageElement );

RootPanel.get().getElement().appendChild( table );
```

How can I add a listener to the icon? I tried ClickHandler and to put the image on a PushButton and get the Element from this PushButton but all don't work.

But mind, if I add the widget (Image is a Widget) to a panel it works!

```
RootPanel.get().add( colorImage );
```

But I am not working with widgets here but with the Element. So the handler disappears and that's the point I don't get how to preserve this added handler information.

In the end I would like to build a table with different rows where I can click on the icon I get a popup menu and thereby change the colour of the row.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just add a ClickHandler (or a MouseDownHandler if that fits your needs better).

Like this:

```
colorImage.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                // Do something....
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried this before but this does not work. I tried different handlers, FocusWidget, ... no reaction.

Comment: @Paulus: In a project I am currently working on I do exactly this but with a MouseDownHandler (addMouseDownHandler) and it works great, click handlers should work equally good. Please post some more code where you actually try it out but fail. Maybe it is just a stupid typo or something.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my question with a demo suited for onModuleLoad() that shows that this solution don't work.

Comment: @Paulus: It could be that you are just using the element (why? that is not how GWT should be used when building a UI). I guess if you bypass everything GWT does for you you will just have have to add handlers and scripts to the element yourself as well.

Comment: @Fredrik is correct, do not insert just the element. Elements are just tags that show up in the dom, Widgets add in the event support. Actually adding the Image widget to the RootPanel will correctly attach the handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Don't unwrap your widget and append only the DOM elements. The Widget class allows your code to refer to both elements and events at the same time, and deals with possible memory leaks, as well as grouping your code in logical ways.

This might make sense for other frameworks, but in GWT you almost always want to work with the Widgets directly, adding them together, then appending them to the RootPanel.

If you really want to use a html table to build this up, look at the `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.HTMLTable` subclasses, `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Grid` and  `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.FlexTable`. This probably should never be necessary, unless you are adding multiple items to the table - when trying to specify layouts, use actual layout classes.

Answer (score 0):

did you tried to add image.sinkEvents( Event.ONCLICK | Event.MOUSEEVENTS )?

Answer (score 0):

The image has to be inside a focus widget. I don't know why that is, but somewhere the events don't get propagated right and the DOM events don't fire.